# Can't extend ClipDrawable: Verifier rejected class on Android 5

Tags: android

This is my extended `ClipDrawable` class:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.Gravity;

public class ProgressClipDrawable extends ClipDrawable {

    public ProgressClipDrawable(int color) {
        super(new ColorDrawable(color), Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    }
}
```

When I try to instantiate this class I get the following errors:

```
04-14 20:20:49.535 7257-7257/com.example.app I/art: Verification error in java.lang.Object com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable.access$super(com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])
04-14 20:20:49.535 7257-7257/com.example.app I/art: java.lang.Object com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable.access$super(com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) failed to verify: java.lang.Object com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable.access$super(com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]): [0x35] 'this' argument 'Reference: com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable' not instance of 'Unresolved Reference: android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper'
04-14 20:20:49.535 7257-7257/com.example.app E/art: Verification failed on class com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable in /data/data/com.example.app/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex because: Verifier rejected class com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable due to bad method java.lang.Object com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable.access$super(com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])
04-14 20:20:49.536 7257-7257/com.example.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

And the exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable due to bad method java.lang.Object com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable.access$super(com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) (declaration of 'com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable' appears in /data/data/com.example.app/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex)
```

What's interesting is that everything works fine on Android < 5. And I get this crash only on a device running on Android 5.1.1.

There's a method being mentioned:

```
java.lang.Object com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable.access$super(com.example.app.ProgressClipDrawable, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])
```

But I don't have any such methods with such signatures.

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was with the `Gradle` plugin. I just had to downgrade to `1.5.0` from `2.0.0` and everything works fine.

The reason for the exception is related to the fact that in API 23 `ClipDrawable` extends `DrawableWrapper`. And prior to API 23 there was no `DrawableWrapper`, instead `ClipDrawable` was extending `Drawable` itself. And in my gradle file I set `compileSdkVersion` to 23, but the device uses API 22. Still, I'm not sure, why using gradle 2.0.0 produces an apk that doesn't work...